# Deadlock with buffered channel

Tags: go, goroutine

I have some code that is a job dispatcher and is collating a large amount of data from lots of TCP sockets.  This code is a result of an approach to [Large number of transient objects - avoiding contention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748628/large-number-of-transient-objects-avoiding-contention/41749224?noredirect=1#comment70692534_41749224) and it largely works with CPU usage down a huge amount and locking not an issue now either.

From time to time my application locks up and the "Channel length" log is the only thing that keeps repeating as data is still coming in from my sockets.  However the count remains at 5000 and no downstream processing is taking place.

I *think* the issue might be a race condition and the line it is possibly getting hung up on is `channel <- msg` within the `select` of the `jobDispatcher`.  Trouble is I can't work out how to verify this.

I suspect that as select can take items at random the goroutine is returning and the shutdownChan doesn't have a chance to process.  Then data hits inboundFromTCP and it blocks!

Someone might spot something really obviously wrong here. And offer a solution hopefully!?

```
var MessageQueue = make(chan *trackingPacket_v1, 5000)

func init() {
    go jobDispatcher(MessageQueue)
}

func addMessage(trackingPacket *trackingPacket_v1) {
    // Send the packet to the buffered queue!
    log.Println("Channel length:", len(MessageQueue))
    MessageQueue <- trackingPacket
}

func jobDispatcher(inboundFromTCP chan *trackingPacket_v1) {
    var channelMap = make(map[string]chan *trackingPacket_v1)

    // Channel that listens for the strings that want to exit
    shutdownChan := make(chan string)

    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-inboundFromTCP:
            log.Println("Got packet", msg.Avr)
            channel, ok := channelMap[msg.Avr]
            if !ok {
                packetChan := make(chan *trackingPacket_v1)

                channelMap[msg.Avr] = packetChan
                go processPackets(packetChan, shutdownChan, msg.Avr)
                packetChan <- msg
                continue
            }
            channel <- msg
        case shutdownString := <-shutdownChan:
            log.Println("Shutting down:", shutdownString)
            channel, ok := channelMap[shutdownString]
            if ok {
                delete(channelMap, shutdownString)
                close(channel)
            }
        }
    }
}

func processPackets(ch chan *trackingPacket_v1, shutdown chan string, id string) {
    var messages = []*trackingPacket_v1{}

    tickChan := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 1)
    defer tickChan.Stop()

    hasCheckedData := false

    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-ch:
            log.Println("Got a messages for", id)
            messages = append(messages, msg)
            hasCheckedData = false
        case <-tickChan.C:

            messages = cullChanMessages(messages)
            if len(messages) == 0 {
                messages = nil
                shutdown <- id
                return
            }

            // No point running checking when packets have not changed!!
            if hasCheckedData == false {
                processMLATCandidatesFromChan(messages)
                hasCheckedData = true
            }
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(time.Second * 60)):
            log.Println("This channel has been around for 60 seconds which is too much, kill it")
            messages = nil
            shutdown <- id
            return
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 01/20/16**

I tried to rework with the `channelMap` as a global with some mutex locking but it ended up deadlocking still.

---

Slightly tweaked the code, still locks but I don't see how this one does!!
https://play.golang.org/p/PGpISU4XBJ

---

**Update 01/21/17**
After some recommendations I put this into a standalone working example so people can see.  https://play.golang.org/p/88zT7hBLeD

It is a long running process so will need running locally on a machine as the playground kills it.  Hopefully this will help get to the bottom of it!

Comment: Get a stack trace when the deadlock happens and see where each goroutine is blocked.

Comment: I tried that but there is 300 or so goroutines and couldn't make out where the block was!

Comment: Would any pprof commands help here at all?

Comment: If you're in the `inboundFromTCP` case, and the corresponding `processPackets` shuts down, it's not removed from the map and therefor you get a deadlock. This smells of over-using channels, but I don't have a clear picture of the problem so I'm not sure which direction to send you.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was pointed down this route from a single shared map that was consuming a ton of CPU and this does work (albeit that issue!)

Comment: A shared map with a mutex is a very common, and there's no reason to avoid something that simple for a nest of goroutines and channels. Hiding that single point of contention behind more layers of complexity obviously doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That is what I started with however, and the CPU was much higher with wait times on the locks around 1 second. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748628/large-number-of-transient-objects-avoiding-contention/41749224?noredirect=1#comment70692534_41749224

Comment: You still have that same single point of contention here, you just traded a mutex for channels, which means that you can achieve the same with the mutex and/or a happy balance of the two. Start with a struct to contain the map and mutex, and add methods which take the lock only as needed, which makes map access easier to reason about compared to the global variables.

Comment: Don't listen to channel haters. Yes, a channel is a lock, just like a mutex. But a channel architecture can work *really well*. Once you get the bugs out as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your problem is getting stuck doing this `channel <- msg` at the same time as the other goroutine is doing `shutdown <- id`.

Since neither the `channel` nor the `shutdown` channels are buffered, they block waiting for a receiver. And they can deadlock waiting for the other side to become available.

There are a couple of ways to fix it. You could declare both of those channels with a buffer of 1.

Or instead of signalling by sending a shutdown message, you could do what Google's context package does and send a shutdown signal by closing the shutdown channel. Look at https://golang.org/pkg/context/ especially `WithCancel`, `WithDeadline` and the `Done` functions.

You might be able to use context to remove your own shutdown channel and timeout code.

And JimB has a point about shutting down the goroutine while it might still be receiving on the channel. What you should do is send the shutdown message (or close, or cancel the context) and continue to process messages until your `ch` channel is closed (detect that with `case msg, ok := <-ch:`), which would happen after the shutdown is received by the sender.

That way you get all of the messages that were incoming until the shutdown actually happened, and should avoid a second deadlock.

Comment: I just put a working standalone example up at https://play.golang.org/p/88zT7hBLeD, am hoping this might help get to the bottom of it!  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I'm new to Go but in this code here

```
case msg := <-inboundFromTCP:
        log.Println("Got packet", msg.Avr)
        channel, ok := channelMap[msg.Avr]
        if !ok {
            packetChan := make(chan *trackingPacket_v1)

            channelMap[msg.Avr] = packetChan
            go processPackets(packetChan, shutdownChan, msg.Avr)
            packetChan <- msg
            continue
        }
        channel <- msg
```

Aren't you putting something in channel (unbuffered?) here

```
channel, ok := channelMap[msg.Avr]
```

So wouldn't you need to empty out that channel before you can add the msg here?

```
channel <- msg
```

Like I said, I'm new to Go so I hope I'm not being goofy.  :)

Comment: No, that `channel, ok` is getting a stored channel out of the map. If it does not exist then `ok` is false and the code creates a channel and sets it in the map.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Zan!

Comment: I hope people stop downvoting my answer. The person asking the question also asked for a second set of eyes. I knew my answer had a good chance of being wrong but sometimes just contributing helps others to look at a problem in a different way or consider things they hadn't thought of before. This seems to have been the case with Zan Lynx as his answer seems to indicate that he started thinking about there being a possible problem with channel <- msg being unbuffered based on my answer. At the very least, my answer seems to have prompted another answer and induced more activity on this topic.

Comment: My comment above should definitely in no way be construed as me trying to take credit for Zan's answer.  He obviously is much more knowledgeable in this area than I am and I'm grateful for the explanation he provided to me.  I'm just saying, sometimes even wrong answers help lead to the right one just because they focus on an area that wasn't being previously considered and I don't think that should be punished.